# getting NoMethodError on simple program

Tags: ruby

I am a complete Ruby newb, and am attempting to write a simple program to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa.
  Everything works in my code so far, up until the point when it starts to begin the conversion calculations. 
  When it gets to the first line of conversion (the Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion) I get an error in the terminal that states

> "test.rb:17:in ': undefined method `-' for "45":String
>   (NoMethodError)"

could someone please fill me in on what I am missing? I have tried to google this to no avail, and it could just be because I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. Code Below, thanks in advance!

```
puts "This program will convert temperatures from Celcius to Fahrenheit" 
puts "or Fahrenheit to Celcius"
puts "to begin, please select which unit you are converting from"
puts "enter 0 for Fahrenheit or 1 for Celcius"
unit_from=gets.chomp
puts "please input the temperature"
degrees_from=gets.chomp

#this is the formula for celcius to fahrenheit
Celcius=(degrees_from-32)*(5/9)

#this is the formula for fahrenheit to celcius
Fahrenheit=(degrees_from)*(1.8)+32

if unit_from = 0
    puts Celcius
elsif unit_from =  1
    puts Fahrenheit
else 
    puts "You have entered and invalid option."
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

value for unit_from and degrees_from are both strings, and for obvious reason you cannot do multiplication on a string. So first convert them to integer.

```
unit_from=gets.chomp.to_i
puts "please input the temperature"
degrees_from=gets.chomp.to_i
```

**to_i** is used to convert any string to integer. For eg:
"2" is a string, to convert it to integer

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > "2"
 => "2" 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > "2".class
 => String 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > "2".to_i
 => 2 
2.0.0-p247 :004 > "2".to_i.class
 => Fixnum
```

Also **"="** is an assignment operator, ie
a = 2, merely assigns the value 2 to variable a.

to check is a has a value of 2, we need to use **"=="**

```
2.0.0-p247 :006 > a = 2
 => 2 
2.0.0-p247 :007 > puts a
2
 => nil 
2.0.0-p247 :008 > a == 2
 => true
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you guys so much for the help. It's starting to come together now! Much appreciated!

Comment: I tried to, but it says I have to have 15 reputation, and I don't sin e I just started my profile.

Comment: Aha, I see what you're talking about now. Done. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I keep trying, but it isn't taking it. I tried again, but if isn't taking it, I can't do anything else. I'm on mobile, so that may have something to do with.

Answer (score 0):

Testing equality requires two equals, as following

```
if unit_from == 0
    puts Celcius
elsif unit_from ==  1
    puts Fahrenheit
else 
    puts "You have entered and invalid option."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[`gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returns a String:

> **gets(sep=$/) → string or nil**
>   **gets(limit) → string or nil**
>   **gets(sep,limit) → string or nil**
>   Returns (and assigns to `$_`) the next line from the list of files in `ARGV` (or `$*`), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line.

Then you call [`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chomp) on that String and get another String:

> **chomp(separator=$/) → new_str**
>   Returns a new `String` with the given record separator removed from the end of *str* (if present).

That means that you have Strings in `unit_from` and `degrees_from`:

```
unit_from    = gets.chomp
#...
degrees_from = gets.chomp
```

Strings don't know anything about subtraction so `degrees_from-32` gives you an error. If you want to work with integer inputs, then throw in a couple [`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i) calls:

```
unit_from    = gets.chomp.to_i
#...
degrees_from = gets.chomp.to_i
```

The next problem is that `5/9` is integer division so `5/9` is just a complicated way of writing `0`. You want floating point so you should use `5.0/9`, `5/9.0`, `5.to_f/9`, ...

The next problem after that will be that you final `if`:

```
if unit_from = 0
  puts Celcius
elsif unit_from =  1
  puts Fahrenheit
else 
  puts "You have entered and invalid option."
end
```

will always say `puts Celcius`. `unit_from = 0` is an assignment, not a comparison; an assignment in Ruby is also an expression so `if unit_from = 0` is syntactically valid but not logically valid; the value of an assignment is its right hand side so `unit_from = 0` (as an expression) is just `0` and since `0` is truthy in Ruby, you'll always end up in the first branch. You want to use `==` for comparisons:

```
if unit_from == 0
  puts Celcius
elsif unit_from ==  1
  puts Fahrenheit
else 
  puts "You have entered and invalid option."
end
```